# How to check if a number is in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\star}$, where $p$ is the product of two primes?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Like the question says, how can I check if a given number $e$ is in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\star}$, where $p$ is the product of two primes?

It is enough to verify if $\gcd(e, p)=1$? What's the logic behind?

Comment: Did you mean $Z^*_p$ (as in "Z star p")?

Comment: Don't use p for a number that isn't a prime.

Comment: Yes, the group Z star p.

Comment: Edited as clarified by OP in comment.

Comment: The thing is that when $gcd(e,p)=1$ there are integers $a,b$ such that $ae+bp=1$ ([Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)). Therefore, $ae\equiv1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. So, $a$ is the inverse of $e$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: So this condition is enough and that's because it ensures that an inverse of $e$ exists in $Z_p$. That's what I understood.

Comment: @cod If perchance the context is RSA and $\,n = pq\,$ then note that $\,e\,$ is chosen to be coprime to $\,\varphi(n) = (p-1)(q-1),\,$ not coprime to $\, n = pq.\ \ $